# How to write a RewriteRule to pass only the last portion of a path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP file that receives a parameter to print a page, like this:

```
build.php?parameter=print-this-article
```

And what I want is to create a `RewriteRule` with `.htaccess` that allows me to send the very last part to that PHP file, no matter the level, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/article/level-1/level-2/level-3
```

So, in this case the `build.php` will receive the parameter `level-3`.

But if the user types the following URI:

```
www.mysite.com/article/level-1/level-2
```

It would work like this:

```
build.php?parameter=level-2
```

And similarly with `level-1`...

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Trying to better explain the subject

Answer (score 0):

A php example not sure about mod_rewrite

This example is to check the url that is requested then redirect to the proper url needed

```
<?PHP
//check for https or http
$s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : ""; 
//small function to help find the protocol and move it left
$protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
//the basename(dirname()) example will show the folder the url script is in this only echos the if/else will do the work
echo $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
if(basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) == "level-1") header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/build.php?parameter=level-1");
if(basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) == "level-2") header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/build.php?parameter=level-2");
if(basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) == "level-3") header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/build.php?parameter=level-3");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
function strleft($s1, $s2) 
{ 
    return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2)); 
}
```

if redirect doesnt work

```
function redirect($url)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {    
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
        }
    else
        {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; exit;
    }
}
?>
```

for mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oranges.html$ apples.html
```

Once everything is in place, visit the site ending in "/oranges.html"— all of the information displayed will come from the "/apple.html" site.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Comment: That aren't making the site slower? I meam that's the purpose of the htaccess file...

Comment: mod_rewrite is slower but we are talking fractions of a second

Comment: yeah, they are like some milliseconds, so I combine both solutions, PHP and `.htaccess`, can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the level, you must capture part of the request URI. To ensure it is the final part, it must not contain any slashes. This is recognized by this regular expression

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ build.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

The important part is `[^/]`, which is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[...]`, consisting of anything [not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `^` a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I researched more and ended mixing PHP and the `RewriteRule`.

On the `.htaccess` I wrote:

```
# this sends the whole part of the URI that is after the 'article/'
RewriteRule  ^article/(.+)$ build.php?parameter=$1   [L]
```

So if the URI is `www.mysite.com/article/level-1/level-2` the PHP file `build.php` will receive this string `level-1/level-2`.

And in the `build.php` I added this function:

```
   function get_last_parameter($link)
   {
       // to split the string right on the '/'
       $parts = explode("/", $link);
       // to remove empty elements, this helps in case a URI ended with '/' is received
       $parts = array_diff($parts, array(''));
       // take the final element of the array and remove any string that starts with '#', so it won't be confused with sections
       $final_array = explode("#", end($parts));
       // the result is an array of two (or more elements) so send the first one (of this array)
       $parameter = reset($final_array);
       return $parameter;
   }
// ... and wrote the query to select from the database the article
```

The advantage of this method is that I can use all the 'levels' of the URI at the same time, because I will have the complete array.